# How to locate user location to map through ip address in python folium?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, folium

I am using Django REST Framework. Now I can Access User IP from the `request` of user using `django-ipware`.

```
from ipware import get_client_ip
def getlocation(request):
    client_ip, is_routable = get_client_ip(request)
```

It provides me the IP address of the `request` from where user is accessing. Now I want to find out latitude and longitude of that IP through which I can place the user location on the folium map.

```
map1 = folium.Map(location=[latitude,longitude], zoom_start=12, control_scale=True,prefer_canvas=True)

folium.CircleMarker(location = [latitude,longitude],radius = 20, popup= 'Here You Are',fill=True,fill_color="#3186cc",).add_to(map1)

folium.Marker([latitude,longitude], popup ='Your Location').add_to(map1)
```

So How can I get The Latitude and Longitude??

Answer (score 0):

Frist I have to Install `django-ipware` using

```
pip install django-ipware
```

Next Try to Import by

```
from ipware import get_client_ip
import urllib, json
```

now on method that will execute the folium map add these codes

```
    client_ip, is_routable = get_client_ip(request)
    if client_ip is None:
        client_ip="0.0.0.0"
    else:
        if is_routable:
            ip_type="Public"
        else:
            ip_type="Private"

    url = 'https://api.ipfind.com/?ip=' + client_ip
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data1 = json.loads(response.read())
    longitude=data1["longitude"]
    latitude=data1["latitude"]
```

important: If you are on your local server than your ip_address will be private and it is not routable so try to add `try  exception block` where you can pass a static ip address for checking whether you getting `longitude latitude` or not.
my code samples are like

```
    client_ip, is_routable = get_client_ip(request)
    if client_ip is None:
        client_ip="0.0.0.0"
    else:
        if is_routable:
            ip_type="Public"
        else:
            ip_type="Private"
    ip_address = '106.220.90.88'
    try:
        url = 'https://api.ipfind.com/?ip=' + client_ip
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        data1 = json.loads(response.read())
        longitude=data1["longitude"]
        latitude=data1["latitude"]
    except:
        url = 'https://api.ipfind.com/?ip=' + ip_address
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        data1 = json.loads(response.read())
        longitude=data1["longitude"]
        latitude=data1["latitude"]
```

Then you can use that latitude and longitude for placing on folium Map.

(One more way is to use DATABASE for getting latitude and longitude of that ip address.)